# Are there any portraits of Joseph Fourier other than this one?

Tags: mathematicians, fourier

[Jean-Baptiste Joseph Fourier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Fourier) was a French mathematician and physicist who initiated the investigation of Fourier series. The following is the only portrait of Fourier that I know of. Are there any portraits of Fourier other than this one?

[image: Painting of Fourier]

Comment: You mean a colored engraved portrait ?

Comment: I meant any other portrait than this known portrait regardless if its colored or not @JeanMarieBecker

Comment: You can find a certain number of them on the web, beginning by the  Wikipedia article devoted to J.B. Fourier. A nice lively document is [this one](https://lewebpedagogique.com/josephfourier/2019/07/17/fourier-tableau-miracule/) (in French) whose title means, "The miraculously preserved painting"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a caricature of Fourier and Legendre:
http://www.numericana.com/fame/legendre-fourier.jpg
(This is the only existing portrait of Legendre).

Comment: If the link is broken, this answer loses much of its value.

Comment: In fact these caricatures can be found as well in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Fourier) article on Joseph Fourier

Comment: [Here is a bust of Fourier](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2F2%2F26%2FGrenoble_-_ancien_%25C3%25A9v%25C3%25AAch%25C3%25A9_-_Joseph_Fourier.JPG&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikiquote.org%2Fwiki%2FJoseph_Fourier&tbnid=2zrsCv8R7BolOM&vet=12ahUKEwjjqMy38oz1AhVYEFkFHaHxB88QMygLegUIARD8AQ..i&docid=jQvwuI3YKjfbXM&w=2124&h=3186&itg=1&q=joseph%20fourier&client=ms-android-verizon&ved=2ahUKEwjjqMy38oz1AhVYEFkFHaHxB88QMygLegUIARD8AQ)...

Comment: [plus one from his grave](https://www.google.com/search?q=joseph+fourier&tbm=isch&ictx=1&tbs=rimg:Cds67Ar_1EewaIgjbOuwK_1xHsGioSCds67Ar_1EewaEY0L8LiN2Co3&client=ms-android-verizon&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwibl_zn8oz1AhUUBVkFHRomBogQiRx6BAgAEAQ&biw=384&bih=723#imgrc=UYmAEAZlHeDLHM&imgdii=A_PVgEDf7rV5GM).

Comment: The link in the comment of @Spencer shows at least 5 different portraits (it is clear that they are not reproductions of the same since he wears different cloths).

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko This would be closed as "too basic" on HSE. I don't know about here.

Comment: @Spencer: I do not care. I like the portrait in the link of  
Jean Marie Becker's comment which I did not know). So the post was useful anyway.